# R: Using variable of filtered dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to dynamically change the filling color in geom_bar() depending on the variable of the dataframe. For example, using mtcars:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=rownames(mtcars), y=hp)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity', fill=(ifelse(mtcars$qsec>17.5, "black", "red"))) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
```

This works fine for me.

However, I want to filter the dataframe **beforehand (e.g. only cars with more than 4 cylinders) without building a second dataframe**:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=(mtcars %>% filter(cyl>4)), aes(x=rownames(mtcars), y=hp)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity', fill=(ifelse(mtcars$qsec>17.5, "black", "red"))) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
```

This results in:

```
Error in `geom_bar()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (21)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x`
```

Okay, taking away the dataframe-name in geom_bar() results in: `Error: object 'qsec' not found`

I have no idea how to get access to the actual qsec-variable dynamically without building a second dataframe.

Thank you very much for your comments and ideas for this problem.

Comment: `.data[["qsec"]]` ?

Comment: is it so bad creating a second dataframe? I usually do because I would expect that in `ggplot(data=(mtcars %>% filter(cyl>4)), aes(x=rownames(mtcars), y=hp))` the filtered dataframe and the `rownames(mtcars)` don't match anymore. 
that's where I expect your first error comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The Key point is to filter before hand:

In your code after filtering mtcars there is a mismatch because geom_bar() refers to the original mtcars and not the filtered one:

Here is an approach with some modifications:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl > 4) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = rownames(.), y = hp, fill = ifelse(qsec > 17.5, "black", "red"))) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_identity()+
  labs(x = "id")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `tidyverse`, here is a `dplyr` way to apply your filter and create a variable to use to determine `fill` colors without creating new dataframes.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  filter(cyl>4) %>%
  mutate(fill_color = ifelse(qsec>17.5, "black", "red")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=hp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(fill=fill_color)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black','red')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>